# JS too much recursion on setInterval ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, babylonjs

Greets everyone,

**Update:** Solved it by a workaround, changing:

```
    $numcflsinfpres = dbquery('SELECT fs_sub_id,fs_sub_cnt FROM '.$db_table['moveable_subs'].' WHERE fs_moveable_id='.$numcflinfparr['moveable_id']);
    while($numcflsarr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($numcflsinfpres)) {
        array_push($numcflinfparr['moveable_subs'],$numcflsarr);
    }
```

to a function and used:

```
array_push($numcflinfparr[‘moveable_subs’], get_babylon_sub_object_data($numcflinfparr[‘moveable_id’]));
```

**Old Text:**

hope you can help me out with this:

I wanted to update JS object data by jquery (via $.ajax) by receiving PHP's mysqli_fetch_assoc array. It worked until I started using setInterval to update data every 15 minutes. Since then I get the following error: **Uncaught (in promise) InternalError: too much recursion**.

Also, tried only calling one object update (replacing for..of for a certain objectID), but I had no success. The error occurs on the line of $.ajax statement.

Edit: I could find that it occurs when an associative is pushed to array in this code:

```
function get_babylon_object_data($user,$id) {
    $envobjects = array();
    $envobjectsarr = mysqli_fetch_assoc(dbquery('SELECT object_id,object_user_id FROM '.$db_table['objects'].' WHERE object_id='.$id));
    if(($envobjectsarr['object_id'] ?? 0)>0) {
        $envobjectsarr['object_moveables'] = array();
        if($envobjectsarr['object_user_id']==$user['id']) {
            $numcflinfpres = dbquery('SELECT moveable_id,moveable_user_id,moveable_object_id,moveable_subobject_id FROM '.$db_table['moveable'].' WHERE moveable_object_id='.$envobjectsarr['object_id']);
            while($numcflinfparr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($numcflinfpres)) {
                $numcflinfparr['moveable_subs'] = array();
                $numcflsinfpres = dbquery('SELECT fs_sub_id,fs_sub_cnt FROM '.$db_table['moveable_subs'].' WHERE fs_moveable_id='.$numcflinfparr['moveable_id']);
                while($numcflsarr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($numcflsinfpres)) {
                    array_push($numcflinfparr['moveable_subs'],$numcflsarr);
                }
                array_push($envobjectsarr['object_moveables'],$numcflinfparr);
            }
        }
        $envobjectsarr['object_subobjects'] = array();
        $envsubobjectsres = dbquery('SELECT * FROM '.$db_table['subobjects'].' WHERE subobject_object_id='.$envobjectsarr['object_id']);
        while($envsubobjectsarr=mysqli_fetch_assoc($envsubobjectsres)) {
            $envsubobjectsarr['subobject_moveables'] = array();
            if($envsubobjectsarr['subobject_user_id']==$client['id']) {
                $numflinfpres = dbquery('SELECT moveable_id,moveable_user_id,moveable_object_id,moveable_subobject_id FROM '.$db_table['moveable'].' WHERE moveable_subobject_id='.$envsubobjectsarr['subobject_id']);
                while($numflinfparr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($numflinfpres)) {
                    $numflinfparr['moveable_subs'] = array();
                    $numflsinfpres = dbquery('SELECT fs_sub_id,fs_sub_cnt FROM '.$db_table['moveable_subs'].' WHERE fs_moveable_id='.$numflinfparr['moveable_id']);
                    while($numflsinfparr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($numflsinfpres)) {
                        array_push($numflinfparr['moveable_subs'], $numflsinfparr);
                    }
                    array_push($envsubobjectsarr['subobject_moveables'], $numflinfparr);
                }
            }
            $envobjectsarr['object_subobjects'][$envsubobjectsarr['subobject_object_pos']] = $envsubobjectsarr;
        }
        $envobjects[$id] = $envobjectsarr;
    }
    return $envobjects[$id] ?? array('object_id'=>$id);
}
```

**Error:** Uncaught (in promise) InternalError: too much recursion

```
aUpdateObject Updater.js:15
updateObject Updater.js:8
interval Updater.js:35
(Async: setTimeout handler)
interval Updater.js:32
(Async: setInterval handler)
initUpdater Updater.js:30
setup Central.js:29
onFinish Central.js:28
_decreaseWaitingTasksCount assetsManager.ts:1143
done assetsManager.ts:1176
_onDoneCallback assetsManager.ts:168
run assetsManager.ts:117
runTask assetsManager.ts:389
successHandler sceneLoader.ts:756
ImportMesh sceneLoader.ts:792
(Async: promise callback)
ImportMesh sceneLoader.ts:789
dataCallback sceneLoader.ts:552
GLTFFileLoader glTFFileLoader.ts:652
LoadFile fileTools.ts:343
onReadyStateChange fileTools.ts:457
(Async: EventListener.handleEvent)
addEventListener webRequest.ts:138
retryLoop fileTools.ts:482
requestFile fileTools.ts:485
RequestFile fileTools.ts:519
LoadFile fileTools.ts:342
_loadFile scene.ts:4416
_loadFile glTFFileLoader.ts:866
loadFile glTFFileLoader.ts:647
manifestChecked sceneLoader.ts:582
Database database.ts:69
OfflineProviderFactory database.ts:11
_LoadData sceneLoader.ts:603
ImportMesh sceneLoader.ts:765
runTask assetsManager.ts:379
run assetsManager.ts:114
_runTask assetsManager.ts:1194
load assetsManager.ts:1248
createScene Central.js:36
default Central.js:10
<anonym> index.js:5
InnerModuleEvaluation self-hosted:2325
evaluation self-hosted:2286

>jquery 128
    isPlainObject
    ... (127x?) extend
```

**File:** Updater.js

```
    export class Updater {
        constructor(main) {
            this.objects = {};
            this.upobjects = {};    // update-requests-array
        }

        updateObject(id) {
            if(!this.upobjects[id]) {   // If no update-request ongoing
                this.aUpdateObject(id);
                this.upobjects[id] = id;    // save update-request
            }
        }
    
        async aUpdateObject(id) {
            const aUpdater = this;  // set to use in success function
            $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'path/to/updateData.php',
            dataType:'json',
            data: {user:aUpdater.data, id:id},
            success : function (result) {
                // Update Data, then Models and then UI
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log('error');
                console.log(data);
            }
            });
        }
    
        initUpdater() {
            const updater = this;
            this.interval = window.setInterval(function(){  // For every 15 minutes
                let count = 1;
                for(const object of Object.values(updater.objects)) {   // For every object
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        updater.updateObject(object.id);    // init single object update
                    },count*1000);

                    count++;
                }
            }, 900000);
        }
    }
```

**File:** Central.js

```
// Import BABYLON
// Import Updater.js

    export default class {
        constructor() {
            this.canvas = document.getElementById('renderCanvas');  // Canvas
            this.engine = new BABYLON.Engine(this.canvas, true, { stencil: true }); // prepare engine
        
            this.scene = new BABYLON.Scene(this.engine);    // init scene
            this.createScene();
        }
    
        createScene() {
            this.assetManager = new BABYLON.AssetsManager(this.scene);  // Model Loader
            this.updater = new Updater(this);   // manage object updates

            // this.updater.objects will be filled here and models loading is prepared 

            const central = this;
            window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
                central.engine.resize()
            });

            this.assetManager.onProgress = (remainingCount, totalCount, task) => {
                console.log(remainingCount, totalCount, task.name);
            }

            this.assetManager.onFinish = (tasks) => {   // If all 3d models are loaded
                this.setup();

                this.engine.runRenderLoop(function() {
                    central.scene.render(); // simulate scene
                });
            };
        
            this.assetManager.load();   // Load 3d models
        }

        setup() {
            this.updater.initUpdater();
        }
    }
```

**File:** index.js

```
// Import BABYLON
// Import Central.js

if (BABYLON.Engine.isSupported()) {
    window.central = new Central(); // create Application
}
```

**File:** updateData.php

```
<?PHP
ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', 1800);
define('CENTRAL_ROOT_DIR','..');
include_once(CENTRAL_ROOT_DIR.'/path/to/funcs.php');  // includes get_babylon_object_data()
include_once(CENTRAL_ROOT_DIR.'/path/to/config.php');  // includes DB config      
dbconnect();  // connect to mysql DB
$conf = get_all_config();  // get app configuration
include_once(CENTRAL_ROOT_DIR.'/path/to/definitions.php');  // includes definitions

function get_babylon_object($user,$id) {
    return json_encode(get_babylon_object_data($user,$id)); // get_babylon_object_data updates and returns $user (array) using mysqli_fetch_assoc to get DB data
}
echo get_babylon_object($_POST['user'] ?? array(),$_POST['id'] ?? 0);

dbclose();  // close DB
?>
```

Comment: There is no recursion in the code you provided.

Comment: you mean Updater Class (+constructor) and main code that creates object of Updater Class and then call initUpdater()?

Comment: You haven't provided an "updater class" or constructor, and none of this code calls `initUpdater`. Seems like you just chose to omit a bunch of relevant code? I agree with trincot, I don't see any recursion here.

Comment: Below the `Uncaught (in promise) InternalError: too much recursion.` part of the message should be a list of the called functions. Those will tell you where the recursion happens.

Comment: it occurs when i call first array_push in while of moveable_subs inside get_babylon_object_data()-function. Is there a limit of scope depth for array_push calls or associated array depth in jquery/ajax? On pure php it works on even larger scale with superior object.